# Is it possible to make form using only bare Form Component

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

is it possible to make form in Symfony 2 without using any additional components? only with Form Component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Symfony Form component has some [obligatory dependencies](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/form) on:

- EventDispatcher
- Locale
- OptionsResolver

At the moment, optional dependencies are:

- Validator
- HttpFoundation

Example project demonstrating how to use the Form component without the Symfony2 framework: https://github.com/bschussek/standalone-forms

Comment: Please note that the symfony2 core contributors are trying to remove as much hard dependencies between components as possible for Symfony2.2, I don't know if this is going to happen for the Form component too.

Comment: I don't think it's going to happen in this case. OptionsResolver is a component actually extracted from the Form component. EventDispatcher is heavily used. I'm not fully sure about the Locale.

Comment: The Locale isn't requried if the intl extension is available on your system. If you haven't, you need to require it because it's a 'polyfill' for the intl extension.

Comment: And which is code? to create simple form only with obligatory dependencies? In documentation I cant find it. Thank you.

Comment: You can remove the symfony2 framework specific things and read this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html But we have some great documentation on point of merging in the official documentation, you can read those files here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/1883/files

Comment: Thank you! First link is no use for me. I want use only Form Component. But second seems to be what I need. Thank you very much!

Comment: Locale class from the Locale component provides several additional methods compared to the Locale class from PHP (like getDisplayCountries()). It is used by the Form component no matter if intl extension is enabled (look at the CountryType for example).

Comment: Well, then we need to change some documentation (like [this note](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/form.html#registering))